# Conditional Probability using a Matrix

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

[image]

I understand how to find P1: that is simply:

- P(D1|D0)=0.8
- P(W1|D0)=0.2
- P(D1|W1)=0.4
- P(W1|W0)=0.6

I do not however, understand how to find P2 using the matrix.

Normally I would solve it as such:

use a tree diagram...

ex. raining day 3, given it rained on the first day

P(D2|D0) = P(D2 ∩ D0)/P(D0) =0.72, and repeat for all

How do I solve P2 using a matrix for part (a)? Or are they asking me to solve for P2 (using any technique) and then complete part (b) and (c)

basically what I learn from this is:

Pi = (P1)^i

that is you must square the matrix 'i'th times to find the probabilities for wet/dry days since the first day.

Comment: Slight note. Modify the title to mention markov chains (for fellow users later on) what do you think? And mathjax the equations to make it look better also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More completely:

Given $D_n$ as the event of a day $n$ being dry, and $W_n$ being the complementary event of it being wet that day.

Your matrix *should* be defined thus: $P_i = \begin{bmatrix}P(D_n \mid D_{n-i}) & P(W_n \mid D_{n-i}) \\ P(D_n \mid W_{n-i}) & P(W_n \mid W_{n-i})\end{bmatrix}, \forall n$

Now by the law of total probability: $$P(D_n \mid D_{n-i}) = P(D_n \mid D_{n-1})P(D_{n-1}\mid D_{n-i})+P(D_n \mid W_{n-1})P(W_{n-1}\mid D_{n-i})\\P(D_n \mid W_{n-i}) = P(D_n \mid D_{n-1})P(D_{n-1}\mid W_{n-i})+P(D_n \mid W_{n-1})P(W_{n-1}\mid W_{n-i})\\P(W_n \mid D_{n-i}) = P(W_n \mid D_{n-1})P(D_{n-1}\mid D_{n-i})+P(W_n \mid W_{n-1})P(W_{n-1}\mid D_{n-i})\\P(W_n \mid W_{n-i}) = P(W_n \mid D_{n-1})P(D_{n-1}\mid W_{n-i})+P(W_n \mid W_{n-1})P(W_{n-1}\mid W_{n-i})$$

So it follows $P_i = P_1 P_{i-1} = P_1^i$

$$P_i = \begin{bmatrix}0.8 & 0.2 \\ 0.4 & 0.6\end{bmatrix}^i$$

So: $$\begin{align}
\because P(D_2\mid D_0) & = P(D_2\mid D_1)P(D_1\mid D_0) + P(D_2\mid W_1)P(W_1\mid D_0)
\\ & = 0.72
\\ \ldots
\\[2ex]\therefore P_2 & = \begin{bmatrix}0.8 & 0.2 \\ 0.4 & 0.6\end{bmatrix}^2
\\[1ex] & = \begin{bmatrix}0.8 & 0.2 \\ 0.4 & 0.6\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0.8 & 0.2 \\ 0.4 & 0.6\end{bmatrix}
\\[1ex] & = \begin{bmatrix}0.8\times 0.8+ 0.2\times 0.4 & 0.8\times 0.2 + 0.2\times 0.6 \\ 0.4\times 0.8 + 0.6\times 0.4 & 0.4\times 0.2 + 0.6\times 0.6\end{bmatrix}
\\[1ex] & = \begin{bmatrix}0.72 & 0.28 \\ 0.56 & 0.44\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$

and so forth

Hint: Also $P_4=P_2^2$